# this.props.xyz is not a function when child calls parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Currently, I have a small issue, where when using a callback function from one child component, everything renders fine, and on the other, it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

**App.js**

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.loggedInCallback = this.loggedInCallback.bind(this);
    this.renderApplicationContent = this.renderApplicationContent.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      user: null
    }
  }

  loggedInCallback = (status, user = null) => {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: status,
      user: user
    })
  }

  renderApplicationContent = () => {
    if (this.state.loggedIn === false) {
      return <LoginForm updateLoginStatus={this.loggedInCallback} />
    } else {
      return <UserData updateLoginStatus-={this.loggedInCallback} user={this.state.user} />;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="Impact logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Impact</h1>
        </header>

        <div className="App-content">
          {this.renderApplicationContent()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UserData.js**

This is where I get this error: https://screenshot.click/03-31-21ut0-rxzrk.jpg

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './UserData.css';

export default class UserData extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
          Logout
        </button>
        <div>
          ID: {this.props.user}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what's causing this error. I thought it was a binding error, and perhaps it still is, but I can't seem to figure out where the lack of binding is causing the issue. I am running into no errors when using the same thing on the `LoginForm` component, and that's doing pretty much everything identically.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that are a problem in your code

**First:** a typo `updateLoginStatus-={this.loggedInCallback}` wherein instead of assignment operator you used `-=`. Correct that to `updateLoginStatus={this.loggedInCallback}`

**Second:** calling a function from child

```
<button onClick={this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
```

it should be

```
<button onClick={() =>this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
```

since, when you write `onClick={this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}`, whenever the component renders `onClick` handler will be evaluated causing the `setState` in parent to be called which in turn will lead to an infinite loop. You need to assign a `function` to the `onClick` event handler

Answer (score 0):

```
return <UserData updateLoginStatus-={this.loggedInCallback} user={this.state.user} />;
                                  ^ remove this dash
```

Also in

```
<button onClick={this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
```

You probably want to pass a function that runs `updateLoginStatus` as opposed to running it at render time, so pass in an arrow function:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.updateLoginStatus(false)}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your code:

```
return <UserData updateLoginStatus-={this.loggedInCallback} user={this.state.user} />;
```

Remove the - sign, make it:

```
return <UserData updateLoginStatus={this.loggedInCallback} user={this.state.user} />;
```